# IRedMail server rejecting mails

Tags: postfix, email-server, iredmail

Hi I have installed my web mail. and I found it's listed on spamhaus. so I am tring to receive verify email them, this email is rejected.

Logs:

```
Feb  9 17:44:01 mail postfix/postscreen[2033648]: CONNECT from [193.190.148.132]:33436 to [xxx.xxx.xxx]:25
Feb  9 17:44:01 mail postfix/dnsblog[2033651]: warning: dnsblog_query: lookup error for DNS query 132.148.190.193.zen.spamhaus.org: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=132.148.190.193.zen.spamhaus.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb  9 17:44:07 mail postfix/postscreen[2033648]: PASS NEW [193.190.148.132]:33436
Feb  9 17:44:07 mail postfix/smtpd[2033670]: warning: hostname mail-out2.spamhaus.org does not resolve to address 193.190.148.132: Name or service not known
Feb  9 17:44:07 mail postfix/smtpd[2033670]: connect from unknown[193.190.148.132]
Feb  9 17:44:07 mail postfix/smtpd[2033670]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[193.190.148.132]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
Feb  9 17:44:08 mail postfix/smtpd[2033670]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[193.190.148.132]: 450 4.7.1 <mail-out2.spamhaus.org>: Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<noreply@spamhaus.org> to=<postmaster@my-domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-out2.spamhaus.org>
Feb  9 17:44:08 mail postfix/smtpd[2033670]: disconnect from unknown[193.190.148.132] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
```

I have search to fix this issue, I found that the issue should be in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

some properties from `main.cf`:

```
# HELO restriction
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname

postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
        zen.spamhaus.org*2
        bl.spamcop.net*1
        b.barracudacentral.org*1
#    zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
#    b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken DNS. The address `193.190.148.132` resolves to `mail-out2.spamhaus.org.` and `mail-out2.spamhaus.org.` resolves to `193.190.148.132`. Your system is unable to resolve `193.190.148.132` properly and marks it as `unknown`.

Comment: thanks for your help, in file `/etc/resolv.conf` nameserver is `127.0.0.53`, I changed it to 8.8.8.8, but after reload service it's undo the change,

Comment: `127.0.0.53` means that you are most likely running `systemd-resolved` and it controls `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Read its documentation to configure it properly.